# Проблема с парсингом XML

Tags: c#, xmlparser

Пытаюсь распарсить простенький xml-файл

```
-<root>  
    -<content>
       -<category title="Затворы дисковые" icon="zatvor_diskovyi" subtitle="УК 99068, УК 99025 (PN 2,5 МПа)">        
             <action title="Общие данные" screenUrl="zatvor_disk_specification.xml" type="Specification"/>       
             <action title="Конструкция" screenUrl="zatvor_disk_rotator.xml" type="Rotator"/>   
             <action title="Принцип действия" screenUrl="zatvor_disk_princip_deistviya.xml" type="Video"/>
             <action title="Чертёж общего вида" screenUrl="zatvor_disk_chertej.xml" type="TextImageView"/>
        </category>
   -<category title="Затворы какие-то еще" icon="another_zatvor" subtitle="УК 432428, УК 32143 (PN 23,5 МПа)">
             <action title="Same_Общие данные" screenUrl="Same_zatvor_disk_specification.xml" type="Same_Specification"/>
             <action title="Same_Конструкция" screenUrl="Same_zatvor_disk_rotator.xml" type="Same_Rotator"/>
             <action title="Same_Принцип действия" screenUrl="Same_zatvor_disk_princip_deistviya.xml" type="Same_Video"/>
             <action title="Same_Чертёж общего вида" screenUrl="Same_zatvor_disk_chertej.xml" type="Same_TextImageView"/>
        </category>
     </content>    
</root>
```

Соответственно сделал 3 класса:

Action

```
public class action
{
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public String type;
    [XmlAttribute("title")]
    public String title;
    [XmlAttribute("screenUr1")]
    public String screenUrl;
}
```

Category

```
public class category
{

    [XmlArray("category")] [XmlArrayItem("action")] 
    public action[] category;
    [XmlAttribute("title")] 
    public String title;
    [XmlAttribute("subtitle")] 
    public String subtitle;
    [XmlAttribute("icon")]
    public String icon;
}
```

CategoryContainer

```
[XmlRoot("root")]

public class CategoryContainer
{

    [XmlArray("content"), XmlArrayItem("category")] 
    public category[] content;


    public static CategoryContainer load(string path)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CategoryContainer));
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
        return serializer.Deserialize(stream) as CategoryContainer;
    }

}
```

Пока что для удобства все скидываю в String.
Как можно заметить, получается что в классе category у меня также есть и массив с названием category. Если поменять имя класса, то в классе CategoryContainer перестает работать строка:

```
    [XmlArray("content"), XmlArrayItem("category")] public category[] content;
```

Если же поменять имя массива, то соответственно перестает работать строка в классе category:

```
    [XmlArray("category")] [XmlArrayItem("action")] public action[] category;
```

Есть ли какие-то варианты решения, используя именно XMLSerializer? Если нет, то как тогда лучше сделать?

Comment: В чём, собственно, вопрос?

Comment: Вопрос в том, возможно ли сделать так, чтобы при изменении, к примеру имени public action[] category на public action[] actionList, данные из XML все равно туда падали.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня работает так:

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class CategoryContainer
{
    [XmlArray("content")]
    [XmlArrayItem("category")]
    public Category[] Content { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    [XmlElement("action")] // <----------
    public Action[] ActionList { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string title { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string icon { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string subtitle { get; set; }
}

public class Action
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string title { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string screenUrl { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

И я на вашем месте бы переименовал атрибуты:

```
    [XmlAttribute("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
```

и т. д. А ещё оберните `stream` в `using`: `using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path)) return ...`.

---

Совет: проще всего заставить Visual Studio сгенерировать правильные классы при помощи такого трюка: поместите XML в буфер, выберите Edit → Paste Special → Paste XML as classes. Для вас создастся валидный, хотя и неоптимальный набор классов, которые уже можно упрощать.